# Array on Ctypes

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

What is the difference between:

```
c_int(24)
24 * c_int
(24 * c_int)()
(24 * c_int)

>>>c_int(24) == 24 * c_int
False
>>> 24 * c_int == (24 * c_int)
True
>>> 24 * c_int == (24 * c_int)()
False
```

When I'm asking the difference it means what option above is a real array for 24 integer elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> c_int(24) # Create instance of c_int (c_long is an alias)
c_long(24)

>>> 24 * c_int # Creates an 24-element array type (NOT an instance)
<class '__main__.c_long_Array_24'>

>>> (24 * c_int)() # Creates an instance of a 24-element array.
<__main__.c_long_Array_24 object at 0x00000000029871C8>

>>> (24 * c_int)  # Same as second one.  Creates type.
<class '__main__.c_long_Array_24'>
```

So the third one creates your real array for 24 integer elements.